# Matching streamed file signature

Tags: java, mp3, aac

I'm trying to determine file type which is being recieved through a stream (in order to name it with the proper file extension). I've written `determineFormat(String str)` method which is feed by `bytesToHex()` method (bytes are from the buffer). Unfortunately this doesn't work as expected; `determineFormat()` always return `.aac` extension even though `.mp3` is being recived.

```
 public String determineFormat(String str)  {

    Pattern aacPattern = Pattern.compile("FFF1|FFF9");
    Pattern mp3Pattern = Pattern.compile("494433|FFFB");

        Matcher matcher = aacPattern.matcher(str);
        if(matcher.find())  {
            return "aac";

        }

     matcher = mp3Pattern.matcher(str);
    if(matcher.find())  {
        return "mp3";
    }

    return "unknown";
}
```

I feed my `determineFormat()` method using this:

```
public String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    int v;
    for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
        v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem reveals to be simpler than it seemed to be. I was testing my app with `MPEG-2 Audio Layer 3 with ID3v2`. I've decided to read the raw "HexToString` output:

```
0DCB1C992B37173740244875C143D50ACDBA0422CD01D73D3C78F05ED7BBC2B33F9D78A7FFF342C0241C6B56B11EC1867984C20F42A4FAC5B9C0
42220314C006D94E124673CD4CC27FC2FCE12215410F12086BE5A3EDFC6DB2BEB0EAEC6EAAA4BF997FFB3337F914AB1A89C808EA6D338912D72E
99CE11E899999D3AE1092590FB2B71D736DC544B0AFD1035A3FFF340C00E178B62E5BE48C46F04B8EFC106AE3F17DDE08B5FD48672EBEABB216A
8438B6FB3B33BF91D3F3EBFCE14184320532ABA37FFD59BFF6ABAD1AA9AADEE73220679D2C7DDBAB766433A99D8CA752B383067465691750A24A
00F32A5078E29258F6D87A620AFFF342C00A158B22E5BE5944BAE8BA2C54739BE486B719A76DF5FD984D5257DBEAC43B238598EFAB3592DE8DD5
```

The "real" file signature reveals to be `FFF3`. After that I've found this site, which describes mpeg Layer 3 files: http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/PRONOM/Format/proFormatSearch.aspx?status=detailReport&id=687&strPageToDisplay=signatures . Finally I was able to get my code to work nicely with fixed patterns:

```
Pattern aacPattern = Pattern.compile("(FFF1|FFF9)");
Pattern mp3Pattern = Pattern.compile("(FFF3|FFFA|FFFB)");
```

At the beginning I was mislead by information about signatures I got from this site: http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html

Comment: Still, if you use that Pattern you posted and call ``matcher.find()`` on it, it will search all bytes you provide. So it will return "AAC" if the file contains the byte sequence ``FFF1`` *anywhere*. I'd add ``^`` to the regex in order to match that byte sequence only from beginning of the byte stream.

Comment: `Pattern.compile("^(FFF3|FFFA|FFFB)")` is not working as the file signature is usually not at the beginning of the stream.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you match your pattern against the whole file. Change the patterns to

```
Pattern aacPattern = Pattern.compile("^(FFF1|FFF9)");
Pattern mp3Pattern = Pattern.compile("^(494433|FFFB)");
```

And then of course it's enough if you pass in only the first couple of bytes. For getting the bytes in hex you could rather do something easy like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (byte b : bytes) {
    sb.append(String.format("%02X", b));
}
// sb.toString();
```

Comment: This wasn't the cause of the problem but +1 for "getting the bytes" method.

Comment: Then please tell the world what the reason was. I tried your code with an MP3, an AAC and a text file. It worked with my suggested fix for all files, without it I just got "AAC" for result.

Comment: I've posted my answer below.